# Formula for the projected area of a disk onto a line?

Tags: geometry

Does anybody have the formula for the projected area (sum along one dimension) of a disk onto a line as a function of the coordinates on that line?

I ended up drawing a high resolution circle and summing the values along the vertical, but that feels dirty.

Comment: Draw a figure to show us what you mean. There are many projections of a disk to a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to get the length of this green line, right?

[image]

Using the Pythagoras theorem, you can figure out that it is:
$$2\sqrt{r^2-d^2}$$

Comment: This is the length of the intersection.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the measure of the interval onto which the disk projects, this is known to be the diameter.

If you mean the measure weighted by the transverse width, this is known to be the area.

Whatever the line.